# Puppet - npm - grunt install locally error

Tags: gruntjs, npm, vagrant, puppet

I'm trying to install grunt locally with the following define

```
nodejs::npm { '/vagrant/var/www:grunt':
  ensure  => present,
  install_opt => '--save-dev --no-bin-links',
}
```

This define is part of the [puppetlabs nodejs module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/nodejs) and is used in the following setting:

1. OSX 10.9.2
2. Vagrant 1.5.0
3. Puppet 3.2.3
4. Virtualbox 4.3.10
5. Virtualbox guest 4.3.10
6. Node 0.10.26
7. Npm 1.4.6

When I run vagrant provision I get the following error

```
ERR! Error: EPERM, chown '/vagrant/var/www/node_modules/grunt/package.json'
```

A more detailed log can be found here -> [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/N1qUCUyh)

I've read about some issues regarding shared folders and symlinks and that it can be fixed by setting the npm install option --no-bin-links ([Source article](http://www.conroyp.com/2013/04/13/symlink-shenanigans-nodejs-npm-express-vagrant/))
Another article I've found explained a solution to allow symlinks to be created inside a shared vb folder.

Sadly these solutions don't solve my problem.

The funny thing is that when I ssh into the box and execute the following command direcly

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

everything works fine...

### UPDATE

1. When the directory is changed to a path outside the shared folder (in this case /vagrant) the command is successfully executed
2. Changing / setting the user does not fix the problem. e.g. vagrant or root
3. When I call the command with sudo everything works fine, but is bad practice...
4. It also only occurs if you use shared folders through NFS. I switched to Rsync to sync the folder between host and guest and the problem did not occur...

I hope someone could help me figure this thing out, because I'm kinda stuck ;)

Comment: Could you try running the same puppet instruction in a different directory, one which is not a shared folder? Could you also try the command with the vagrant user (I am using chef so I'm not sure about the way puppet does it, but with chef everything is run with sudo and one has to instruct the command to run as a specific user)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I specified a directory outside the shared folder and it gave no errors, so this looks like a shared folder permission problem...

Specifically setting the user to 'vagrant' does not help when the directory is pointing inside a shared folder

Comment: @cocheese did you resolve this? I'm experiencing similar problems when logged into a vagrant box on OSX

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm the 1st point of the update works.